# communicating between two different master clustesr nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a web application where I am clustering the `express` app. I also need to cluster another module where it needs to be receiving jobs from the `express cluster`. I do not want to `fork` a new process every time request is made because I would like to allocate only specific amount of resources. But I don't want to be clustering many processes in every express cluster because that would be a waste. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: "But I don't want to be clustering many processes in every express cluster because that would be a waste" - I don't understand this. Can you explain? There is only one express process and some other workers, isn't it?

Comment: yes but other workers are practically other processes aren't they? because they have their own thread @DylanDang

Comment: Yes of course. But you can send message from master to workers and otherwise using `message` event: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message

Comment: @DylanDang yes I know but I want to be able to communicate between two different masters

Comment: If you're using native cluster library, you can only have 1 master. However, if you want 2 express apps to be able to communicate, you can consider using IPC, or even classical socket (HTTP) way.